# Rails Server stop suddenly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> `PS C:\Users\Dan Koyuki\Documents\Course\Rails\anothertest> rails s Booting Puma Rails 7.1.1 application starting in development Run` bin/rails server --help `for more startup options SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable! SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable! SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable! Puma starting in single mode... Puma version: 6.4.0 (ruby 3.2.2-p53) ("The Eagle of Durango") Min threads: 5 Max threads: 5 Environment: development PID: 4312 Listening on http://[::1]:3000 Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000 Use Ctrl-C to stop Started GET "/home" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-10-16 16:23:28 +0700 ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC Processing by ScreenController#home as HTML PS C:\Users\Dan Koyuki\Documents\Course\Rails\anothertest>`

i try to open home route, but then the server stop without error...
its been like that when i try to read documents from firestore...

im new to rails.. and just follow the tutorials now. the tutorial seems to use rails 7.0 while mine is 7.1 (i dont know if there a big difference or not between these version..)